# Todoist - Workaround to Emoji display issue

Tags: google-chrome, unicode

Todoist allows you to insert emojis into your project titles, label names, etc.  This is very helpful especially for those who are more visually oriented.

The only problem, and I realize it's probably one that doesn't affect huge numbers of people, is that they appear to use a method of inserting these that creates an image tag within the element and populates it by the stored image on this host: https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/.  The problem is, that for me at least, this domain is blocked where I work, which is a government facility.  I don't believe I can get them to unblock it, so I'm looking for workarounds.

I've noticed some sites that I can actually see emojis use an  tag instead, and I've tried to insert this (both htmlencoded and not), but Todoist strips away certain characters like '<' and '>' rendering this just text.  I've also tried entering the &# code for emojis but that also does not seem to work in Todoist.

I finally found that Github of all places uses a similar method as todoist, but does so using a different domain that isn't blocked, specifically http://www.webpagefx.com/.  If I insert one of these emoji sources into the page via Chrome Browser tools in the place of the https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/ source, it shows up.  But I'm not sure how this can be done in a more automated way.  About the only thing I can think of is using something like Tampermonkey, but am I missing some here?  Any other way I might be able to do this without developing a Tampermonkey script?